# How to randomly set a fixed number of elements in each row of a tensor in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

I was wondering if there is any more efficient alternative for the below code, without using the "for" loop in the 4th line?

```
import torch
n, d = 37700, 7842
k = 4
sample = torch.cat([torch.randperm(d)[:k] for _ in range(n)]).view(n, k)
mask = torch.zeros(n, d, dtype=torch.bool)
mask.scatter_(dim=1, index=sample, value=True)
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is to create an `n` by `d` mask tensor, such that in each row exactly `k` random elements are True.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way to do this with no loop. Let's start with a random matrix where all elements are drawn iid, in this case uniformly on [0,1]. Then we take the k'th quantile for each row and set all smaller or equal elements to True and the rest to False on each row:

```
rand_mat = torch.rand(n, d)
k_th_quant = torch.topk(rand_mat, k, largest = False)[0][:,-1:]
mask = rand_mat <= k_th_quant
```

No loop needed :) x2.1598 faster than the code you attached on my CPU.

Comment: Nice answer, however, I think I should have provided you with the real values for `n`, `d`, and `k` which I am actually using in my code (I edit the question). With `n=37700`, `d=7842`, and `k=4`, my own code runs around 5s on my CPU, while yours takes around 18s.

Comment: Thanks, so I've updated it and now it is even better and faster for your new values of n,d and k. Mine takes 2.44s while yours takes 5.27s.