# How to randomly set a variable number of elements in each row of a tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to create a zero-one matrix of dimension (n, n). The ones should be placed randomly, with a cap on the number of ones in each row. Let us say I have a list of length n that has the value of cap for each of the n rows. How can I do this in PyTorch?

My question is similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64162672/how-to-randomly-set-a-fixed-number-of-elements-in-each-row-of-a-tensor-in-pytorc/64170973#64170973). The only change I am looking for is, there should be n values of k, corresponding to n rows.

Comment: You can set the first `m` columns of each row to True, then shuffle them https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-shuffle-each-row-of-a-tensor-with-different-shuffling-order-for-each-of-the-row/109772

Comment: I am not sure what is `m` here. Assuming it is the same as `k` in question, `m` cannot be a fixed number. Can you suggest how can I set a different number of columns (pre-decided) for each of the rows?

Answer (score 2):

As explained by [@Marcel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11324994/marcel) in the comments above, you can first set the first `m` values to value `k` then index by permuted indices in order to get a shuffle tensor:

```
>>> n = 10; m = 3; k = 1
>>> x = torch.zeros(n, n)

>>> x[:, :m] = k
tensor([[1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Use [`torch.randperm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randperm.html) to get row-wise column permutations:

```
>>> perm = torch.stack([torch.randperm(10) for _ in range(len(x))])
tensor([[8, 0, 3, 2, 1, 6, 9, 4, 5, 7],
        [5, 7, 1, 4, 8, 0, 6, 9, 2, 3],
        [2, 1, 9, 7, 0, 8, 6, 3, 5, 4],
        [1, 3, 5, 8, 7, 6, 9, 4, 2, 0],
        [7, 6, 0, 5, 2, 9, 1, 8, 4, 3],
        [5, 0, 6, 8, 1, 9, 2, 4, 3, 7],
        [4, 0, 6, 5, 8, 1, 3, 7, 2, 9],
        [5, 3, 4, 9, 0, 1, 7, 6, 8, 2],
        [5, 7, 9, 3, 2, 6, 8, 0, 4, 1],
        [2, 7, 4, 6, 3, 0, 9, 8, 5, 1]])
```

Then use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.gather.html) to index the tensor `x` with `perm`:

```
>>> x.gather(dim=0, index=perm)
tensor([[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Alternatively you can use [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html) straight way with the `value` keyword argument:

```
>>> torch.zeros(n, n).scatter(dim=0, index=perm, value=1)
tensor([[0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

---

If `m` is a tensor itself, you can find a workaround using a combination of `torch.arange` and [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html):

First encode the positions:

```
>>> d = torch.arange(n)[None].repeat(n,1)
>>> x = torch.where(d+m>n, 0, 1)
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Construct the permutation as before:

```
>>> perm = torch.stack([torch.randperm(10) for _ in range(n)])
tensor([[2, 5, 7, 0, 4, 1, 3, 6, 8, 9],
        [7, 4, 9, 5, 6, 0, 3, 1, 2, 8],
        [5, 1, 4, 9, 0, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 6, 0, 2, 3, 1, 7, 5, 4, 8],
        [3, 5, 4, 6, 0, 7, 9, 8, 2, 1],
        [5, 7, 8, 6, 9, 2, 0, 4, 3, 1],
        [8, 3, 9, 0, 6, 2, 5, 7, 4, 1],
        [2, 9, 4, 3, 7, 8, 1, 0, 6, 5],
        [5, 4, 8, 3, 2, 9, 7, 1, 6, 0],
        [8, 7, 3, 6, 5, 4, 2, 0, 9, 1]])
```

Then scatter on `x`:

```
>>> x.scatter(dim=0, index=perm, value=1)
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Comment: I can see that the final tensor has a `m` number of 1s in every row. I want to vary that for every row. Let us say we know how many number of 1s we need in each row. The total number of 1s in each row is specified, just they must be placed in random locations in each row.

Comment: I have edited my answer, see above.

Comment: I need the tensor `m` to be of size (n, ). [This answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-randomly-set-a-variable-number-of-elements-in-each-row-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch/136602) helped me. Thanks for the answer and comments :)

Comment: @Ru11 *"I need the tensor m to be of size `(n, )`"*, this is exactly what the second part of the answer does. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. Somehow `>>> d = torch.arange(n)[None].repeat(n,1)
>>> x = torch.where(d+m>n, 0, 1)` generates same number of 1s in every row for me. I use `m = torch.randint(n, (n,))` to generate `m`. How do you get different number of 1s? I am not understanding something.

Comment: In 2nd example, `m` needs to be a 1D array containing the number of `1`s you want to put in each row. But the shape of `m` does matter. In needs to be shaped `(n, 1)`. For example, you can use `m = torch.randint(n, (n,1))`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch 

n = 5 
top_k = torch.randint(n, (n,))
print(top_k)

# Step 1, generate a variable number of elements in each row
top_k = torch.nn.functional.one_hot(top_k, num_classes=n)
top_k = 1 - torch.cumsum(top_k, dim=1)  # 
print(top_k)

# Step 2, shuffle each row 
indices = torch.argsort(torch.randn((n, n)), dim=1)
result = top_k[torch.arange(top_k.shape[0])[..., None], indices]
print(result)
```

[This answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-randomly-set-a-variable-number-of-elements-in-each-row-of-a-tensor-in-pytorch/136602) posted in PyTorch forum helped me to get what I wanted.